# 2nd monitor not detected by nVidia Server Settings

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I formatted my computer & installed Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit.
I have dual-monitors connected to a 1GB nVidia card.
Previously, it was working fine.
After installing, both monitors did get detected. But after installing restricted drivers (nVidia), the 2nd monitor doesn't show up in nVidia X Server Settings. I have just one - **X Screen 0**. There should be a **X Screen 1**.
Is there a way to manually fix this ?

Comment: Got this problem solved from here - (http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11361383&postcount=20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Screen" in this sense means X Screen, as in the whole viewport of what you see. You can have multiple monitors inside one screen.

The "X Server Display Configuration" section of nvidia-settings should show you your *monitor* settings for a given X Screen:

[image]